# Trouble with Python Installation - Datalab on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-earth-engine

I'm new to Google Earth Engine and since I'm more familiar with Python I decided to (try to) install the Python library. I've been following the instructions found [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-gcp). I'm doing this on my Mac (Mac OS X) and upgraded my Python version to 2.7.14. I installed the Google Cloud SDK and the gcloud datalab component semi-successfully. I say this because I had to add aliases to my bash_profile for the gcloud and datalab commands to work on the Terminal.

I'm on the step where I have to create a Cloud Datalab instance and here's where I'm really running into trouble. Following the instructions, I'm running the following lines on the command line:

```
export CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME=gcr.io/earthengine-project/datalab-ee:latest
export INSTANCE_NAME=datalab-ee-vm-${USER//_/}
datalab create --image-name $CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME $INSTANCE_NAME
```

When I run these lines I just get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've been trying to look at the documentation to see if there's something I need to modify in the three lines above (maybe where it says USER?), but I can't figure it out. I'm thinking that the command is trying to access one of the libraries that I installed but that might not be referenced/linked correctly.

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The problem was that the aliases weren't enough. I had to actually add the location of the Google Cloud SDK installation into my PATH in .bash_profile. Now onto jumping through other hoops for this Python API installation...